# in git, if fix applied to one version, how it is applied to later versions?

Tags: git, version-control

when using git as the repository, assuming the head is at v1.6

if I find a bug in v1.0

```
git stash save "interruption "  # is this necessary?
git checkout v1.0
vi badfile.c
git commit -a -m 'bugger fixed'
```

how is the fix propagated to subsequent versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either merge with head, rebase onto head, or cherrypick.

Option A:

```
1.0-----1.6-----merge
  \             /
   \           /
    -fix-------
```

Option B:

```
 1.0-----1.6-----fix (rebased)
   \             
    \           
     -fix
```

Option C:

```
1.0-----1.6-----fix (cherrypicked)
  \             
   \           
    -fix
```

Comment: in each case - merge/rebase/cherrypick - I must go through each branch v1.1 .. v1.6 and apply the merge/rebase/cherrypick.  is this right?

Comment: yes, if your branches are really like what you say, branches. My answer applies to the case where you have two branches, one with 1.0 as the head, and the other (the latest branch, or `master`) with 1.6 as the head, since 1.0 to 1.6 correspond to individual tags/commits as the question was originally intended.

Answer (score 3):

The stash (or maybe an interim commit that you can later `--amend` to) is necessary to switch branches.

You should cut a branch from the tag so `git checkout -b v1.0-bugfix v1.0` (I prefer calling the branch something like issue42 where 42 is the bug number).

Then fix the change in `badfile.c`

`git checkout master` (assuming you were on master before you switched to `v1.0-bugfix`.

`git merge v1.0-bugfix` to get in the changes into the current version. You will have to merge it into the branches where you want the fix to be present.

`git stash pop` to get back the changes which you kept aside.

The tree will now look something like

```
          (v1.0-bugfix)--------------------------------------------------(fix badfile)
         /                                                                   \   
        /                                                                     \  
       /                                                                       \ 
o---o---(v1.0)---o---(v1.1)---o---o---(v1.2)---(v1.3)---(v.14)---o---(current-head)---(merge)---(head-with-fix)
```

I've marked interesting commits with `(message)` and regular ones with `o`.

Comment: to be clear - fixed on v1.0 and v1.6, but not fixed on v1.0 .. v1.5, unless specifically merged - is that right?